# Can't find Tomcat with STS 4

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, tomcat

I am trying to run my signin service written in STS, but when I try to run it I can't find Apache Tomcat.

Software details are given below:

Spring Tool Suite 4

Version: 4.19.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 202306150758
Revision: 0b474841221064c10c146eca29f6ae369721c1d2

JDK 17

I also tried adding tomcat dependency in `build.gradle` file but still don't see any.

[[image: Image showing STS empty Tomcat Server]